# Sending and Displaying Hex Values on a Web Page using CICS COBOL

Tags: cobol, cics

I want to send a hexadecimal value to the web page via CICSWEB (COBOL).

For example I `MOVE 'DACA' to OT-S` (OT-S is the variable), when I send this variable to web page , The characters 'DACA' are shown instead of showing the equivalent hexadecimal value.

My code is:

```
*************************
MOVE OT-S TO NAMEVAL.
EXEC CICS DOCUMENT CREATE
   DOCTOKEN(TOKEN1)
   TEMPLATE(WBTMP1)
   SYMBOLLIST(SYMLIST1)
   LENGTH(LENGTH OF SYMLIST1)
   DELIMITER(DL1)
END-EXEC.
EXEC CICS WEB SEND DOCTOKEN(TOKEN1)
    CLNTCODEPAGE('8859-1')
END-EXEC.
```

In the above code `NAMVAL` is a variable that must send to symbol in web page.

I expect the equivalent value of hexadecimal (which is a Persian word) to be displayed when this variable is sent to the page, but the same initial value is displayed.

Comment: I doubt [ISO/IEC 8859-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) can display non-Latin characters.  You would probably need to use [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8).

Comment: 0

If your trying to display a language different than the Latin characterset then this page might help you think your approach through. I don't think its as easy as sending special hex values to to display what your thinking and it would make your program difficult to maintain.

I think this page might help http://www.alanwood.net/unicode/htmlunicode.html

Comment: @ebi-rezaei: this question has no "accepted answer" is there anything open here?

Answer (score 1):

You can move [hexadecimal literals](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cobol-zos/6.3?topic=literals-hexadecimal-notation-alphanumeric) in COBOL by using the notation x'DACA' or x"DACA".  I understand this is what you have asked, but as @Hogstrom and @GilbertLeBlanc noted you may need to manipulate code pages to get your desired result.

IBM Enterprise COBOL also supports [national literals and DBCS literals](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cobol-zos/6.3?topic=literals-), and CICS supports specific code pages in documents via the HOSTCODEPAGE option on [DOCUMENT CREATE](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cics-ts/5.6?topic=summary-document-create).